# Shift and Alt keys not working on Ubuntu Unity 23.04

Tags: unity, keyboard, bios

I have an older Asus Laptop that I reformatted and installed Unity. First time using Linux. Got the OS installed pretty easily and it seemed to be working fine. I was poking around with the settings trying to familiarize myself with everything. I think I may have accidentally disabled sticky keys or some other keyboard setting that affects the Shift and Alt keys. The problem arose when I forgot to reset the setting to default before I powered down for the evening. That laptop has I BIOS admin password that requires special characters so I can't input it with out those keys. I tried using a USB keyboard to check if it was a mechanical problem. Same issue. Is there anyway to fix this without taking apart the laptop and resetting the CMOS or NVRAM? Thanks for any help y'all can provide.

Comment: You have two keys each for SHIFT and ALT (one on the right and one on the left). Have you tried using the other SHIFT and/or the other ALT key? Regardless of how it was disabled, if it's having an effect when the OS isn't running, then there's usually some type of hardware switch and/or key combo you can use to toggle the setting. What is the specific make and model?

Comment: Although if it's the sticky keys problem, then open your system settings by clicking on the upper right hand corner of your desktop and then select **System settings**. Accessibility settings are under **Universal Access** (near the bottom of the popup window) — sticky keys is under the **Typing** tab. So **System Settings** > **Universal Access** > **Typing** > **Sticky Keys**.

Comment: Asus Q534UX. Can't access setting cause I'm locked out at the bios password. All of the alt and shift keys are not responding.

Comment: These are the Ubuntu settings. Unless you need BIOS to access Ubuntu.

Comment: So a couple of things about the keyboard. First, there is a number lock in case you're trying to use numbers but also fn+number-lock enables and disables using the number pad as direction keys. If it's a sticky keys setting in your BIOS, then you should still be able to input what you need but of course you have to do things slightly differently.

Comment: Some people are saying you cannot use special characters for the bios password so try to omit the special character from the password. For example, if your password is 12345@67890 then try using 1234567890

Comment: Also there are some [youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lA21n_UPUU0&t=15s) on resetting the bios password using a code. But you will need to press ALT+R. This would also be a good way to know if ALT really does or does not work. Additionally, you should be able to get to some of the non-admin settings by simply pressing ENTER when it asks you for the BIOS password. Here there may be a setting to help you with the keyboard.

Comment: Tried the Alt-R trick already but no luck. I'll try omitting the special characters but before I messed with the settings in Ubuntu the bios password worked just fine with special characters. It is the @ that I need.

Comment: Guess there weren't any special characters. Rookie mistake. Thanks for all the help. You rock!

Comment: Okay. I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread on the ASUS ROG forum](https://rog-forum.asus.com/t5/rog-gaming-notebooks/keyboard-issues-have-me-locked-out-of-bios/m-p/231953/highlight/true#M62926), the ASUS BIOS password should not contain special characters.

So, for example, if your password is 1234@56789, try 123456789 instead.